# Arrays of arrays in CLIPS

Tags: multidimensional-array, clips

I'd like to create an array of array.
For example:  ((a b c) (d e f))

```
(bind ?part1 (create$ a b c))
(bind ?part2 (create$ d e f))
(bind ?structure (create$))
(bind ?structure (insert$ ?structure 1 (create$ ?part1)))
(bind ?structure (insert$ ?structure 2 (create$ ?part2)))
```

This code gives me:

```
(bind ?part1 (create$ a b c))
(a b c)
CLIPS> (bind ?part2 (create$ d e f))
(d e f)
CLIPS> (bind ?structure (create$))
()
CLIPS> (bind ?structure (insert$ ?structure 1 (create$ ?part1)))
(a b c)
CLIPS> (bind ?structure (insert$ ?structure 2 (create$ ?part2)))
(a d e f b c)
CLIPS>
```

Any hints, please?

Thank you
Nico

Answer (score 1):

Multifields can't be nested. I'd suggest using instances if you need to nest values:

```
CLIPS> (defclass VALUES (is-a USER) (multislot values))
CLIPS> (make-instance v1 of VALUES (values a b c))
[v1]
CLIPS> (make-instance v2 of VALUES (values d e f))
[v2]
CLIPS> (make-instance v3 of VALUES (values [v1] [v2]))
[v3]
CLIPS>
```